the usage of phrase 'Leave ... behind'
It's also sourced from some English test of high school in Mainland China.

Hulunbuir's name has been illuminated on the national stage, with the 14th National Winter Games successfully drawing a close on Tuesday February 27, regarded as the most significant comprehensive winter sports event in China after the 2022 Beijing Winter Olympics. This grand event not only leaves behind memories of thrilling moments but acts as an example of the power of sports in enhancing unity and celebrating diversity.

My question is, Can 'leave behind ...' be used like this? 'leave behind memories', does it mean have precious memories or just abandon the memories. I think here the author want to express the former one.
I looked it up in Longman dictionary.
it only has the following meanings, but not including the one the aforementioned author used above.

a) to not take someone or something with you when you leave a place
e.g. I think I might have left my wallet behind.


b) if a person, country, or organization is left behind, they do not develop as quickly or make as much progress as other people, countries etc
e.g. In class, a child with poor eyesight can soon get left behind.


c) (also leave somebody/something behind you) to permanently stop being involved with a person, place, or situation
e.g. It’s time to leave the past behind.


d) (also leave somebody/something behind you) to move away from someone or something
e.g. They had left the city behind and were heading into open country.


e) (also leave something behind you) to produce a thing or situation that remains after you have gone
e.g. He drove off, leaving behind him a trail of blue smoke.

the mess the previous government left behind

The event has finished, but the memories are still there; like a person who has physically gone away but left things behind.

This is the same as sense (e) from your Longman quote. The event came to Beijing, and then when it left Beijing it 'left behind' memories of thrilling moments. It could be understood as either leaving these memories in Beijing or in the minds of the audience around the world (the Olympics also metaphorically visited them via the news and television).

I.e. it didn't take the memories away when it left.

If one is on a journey one would "leave behind" various things, some because they are abandoned as not wanted, and some because they are gifts for other people. When the expression is used with memories either meaning is possible. In your text the author is saying that after the event is gone the memories will remain, and the way the memories are described makes it clear they are precious memories.
